# VS 2010 Debugger: Any way to search an object for a particular value?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, search, visual-studio-2010, object

I am trying to search the "this" object in an ASP.NET MVC 2 for a string value.

In a view, I set the partial view input tag prefix and am trying to figure out how to reference it in the partial view itself.

For example:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m, "templateName", "fieldPrefix");
```

In the partial view, I would like to search the "this" object for my fieldPrefix string to see where the MVC folks decided to store it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ASP.NET scenario, but if I understand correctly you want to search for a string value in the debug watch window. There is no simply way to do this, but you can type ?this in the Immediate window, which will print out *everything* about that object, and then use simple text search (Ctrl+F) to find the specific string you are looking for.